# Expression engine - dynamically outputting custom image sizes with their height and width

Tags: expressionengine

So I have a custom image size i'd like to output, I've tried the following:

```
{profile_logo:thumbnail wrap="image"}
```

But you don't get height and widths which isn't ideal so I tried:

```
{profile_logo}
      <img src="{url:thumbnail}" alt="{title}" width="{width}" height="{height}" />
{/profile_logo}
```

However this outputs the original files width and height, so the only option I'm left with is to hardcode the height and width which isn't ideal

```
{profile_logo}
      <img src="{url:thumbnail}" alt="{title}" width="80" height="52" />
{/profile_logo}
```

Is there anyway to dynamically output the thumbnail height and width? Have tried {width:thumbnail} but it doesn't work.

Cheers!

Comment: Nick, do you have access to the EE beta site? Can you post EE questions there?  http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - there is no stock way to output an image tag with **height** and **width** parameters for custom image sizes from EE file fields.

You can take a look at the [GWCode FileInfo add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gwcode-fileinfo), it could get that info for you from the raw URL (don't use the "wrap" param).

```
{exp:gwcode_fileinfo:single file="{profile_logo:thumbnail}"}
    <img src="{file_url}" width="{image_width}" height="{image_height}" alt="" />
{/exp:gwcode_fileinfo:single}
```

These days I *never* want these parameters on my images, as when doing repsonsive layouts with fluid images make your images resize disproportionately.